# Cakephp how do I overlap images

Tags: php, cakephp

Im wondering if it is possible to overlap 2 images using CakePHP. What Im trying to do here is make default image (a pin drop in googlemap) with a head and an anchor. If the user uploads an images, it will put the uploaded image in the head of the pin drop. Any help is appreciated.

What Ive done so far is display the uploaded image in the google map but it replaces the whole pin drop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It needs a solution using **simply CSS**  **`z-index`** property. ***PHP has nothing to do with the style*** you want to apply.

Use the following syntax-

```
<img src="img1.jpg" style="z-index:1; position:absolute;" width=200 height=200>
<img src="img2.jpg" style="z-index:2; position:absolute;" width=100 height=100>
```

Here **img2.jpg** will appear above **img1.jpg**. The higher the **`z-index`** value the more outer the element will appear.